# Bound between norms of operators implies bound between norms of adjoints

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two operators, such that $B$ is self-adjoint, on a Hilbert space such that $\lVert{A x}\rVert \leqslant \lVert{Bx}\rVert$ for all $x$. Does this imply that $$ \lVert{A^* x}\rVert \leqslant \lVert{B x}\rVert$$ for all $x$?

This is true if $A$ is a normal operator, since then $\lVert{A x}\rVert = \lVert{A^* x}\rVert$. I was wondering if this result holds more generally? I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
We have $$
A^*=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\qquad A^*A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
Let $B=A^*A.$ Then $B^2=B$ and  $\|Ax\|^2=\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle =\langle B^2x,x\rangle=\|Bx\|^2.$ On the other hand for $v=(1,0)^T$ we have $A^*v\neq 0$ but $Bv=0.$